# command prompt anywhere in Windows 7 (native functionality)

Tags: windows-7, registry, command-prompt, windows-explorer

I got this tip from [a website](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/02/09/windows-7-tip-elevated-command-prompt-anywhere/) that "shift + right click" on a folder in explorer in win7 will give us a context menu option by which I can open command prompt right there.

I am looking for a hack that can make this simpler so that whenever I "right click" on a folder in explorer, I always get that "shift + right click" effect.

I am not looking for any info on powertoys.

I need help on exactly what I said above; there has to be some registry hack that makes that "shift" default for every right click on the folder name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the registry key `HKCR\Directory\shell\cmd\Extended`. It works for me on the 64-bit version of Windows 7 Ultimate.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-elevated-command-prompt-in-context-menu/ says you also need to delete `HKCR\Drive\shell\cmd\Extended` if you want the same to apply for drives shown in Computer, and `HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\Extended` for the empty space inside a folder window.

Comment: This is a great key to add to existing menus that you don't want to show up all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same question about viewing the cmd prompt without the key combination recently. I am on Windows 8.1 and found that PleaseStand's solution works perfectly.

[PleaseStand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430775/pleasestand)'s solution mentioned worked great for me:

Delete the registry key `HKCR\Directory\shell\cmd\Extended`. 
It works for me on the 64-bit version of Windows 7 Ultimate.

[This](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-elevated-command-prompt-in-context-menu/) says you also need to delete `HKCR\Drive\shell\cmd\Extended` if you want the same to apply for drives shown in Computer,

And `HKCR\Directory\Background\shell\cmd\Extended` for the empty space inside a folder window.

I might add to anyone who might wonder, `HKCR` means `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`

Comment: Please do not add "thank you" as an answer. When you have enough reputation, you can [upvote helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [award a bounty to helpful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).